# AngularFire sync simple-login-email to profile-email

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

*I'm working off of the sample code inside of [angularfire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed).

How can the Firebase simple-login email value update when the authenticated user updates their profile email on the account page*?

Answer (score 0):

The [account.html](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/partials/account.html) page calls `updateEmail`:

```
<button ng-click="updateEmail()">update email</button>
```

Angular hooks that up to the [AccountCtrl controller](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js#L82):

```
$scope.updateEmail = function() {
    $scope.reset();
    // disable bind to prevent junk data being left in firebase
    $scope.unBindAccount();
    changeEmailService(buildEmailParms());
  };
```

Which invokes the [changeEmailService](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/blob/master/app/js/service.changeEmail.js).

Essentially, the changeEmailService creates a new account, verifies it, and then deletes the old account. Then it updates the data it the /user path. It uses this algorithm of chained promise callbacks:

```
        // execute activities in order; first we authenticate the user
        authenticate()
           // then we fetch old account details
           .then( loadOldProfile )
           // then we create a new account
           .then( createNewAccount )
           // then we copy old account info
           .then( copyProfile )
           // and once they safely exist, then we can delete the old ones
           .then( removeOldProfile )
           .then( removeOldLogin )
           // success
           .then( function() { cb && cb(null) }, cb )
           .catch( errorFn );
```

Comment: So if the user id is user22 and then they change their email their user id would change to say user245? If so, how would you suggest keeping them linked to all of their data?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by their user id. For email/password login, which is the only example where you can change a user's email address, the user id will be something like "kato@domain,com" and the uid will be "password:kato@domain,com". If you are allowing users to change their email address, then you'll have to update their data accordingly.

Comment: When I follow the firebase example code I end up with a structure like: users[simplelogin:1[email:name@address.com,name:Joe],simplelogin:2[email:..,name:..]]. If I change my email it will change my email within the json I just listed, but it won't changed by email within the Registered Users list under the Simple Login tab of the Firebase admin panel. If I change my email address it'll only be in the json file, and I'll need to login with the email address I registered with. I'm looking for a way to change both emails while keeping my json data linked still to the same uid(simplelogin:1).